# getJSON send request with multiline string

Tags: php, javascript, string

I have something like this :

**code.js**

```
var params = {
  option1 : encodeURIComponent("text\n text\n text\n\n\n"), 
  option2 : encodeURIComponent("\n\n\n text")
};
$.getJSON("/update_user_info", params, function(data) {});
```

**/update_user_info**

```
<?php
   foreach($_GET as &$data) $data=urldecode($data);
   /*CODE*/
   echo json_encode($some_result);
?>
```

But my `\n` are removed or replaced with `whitespaces`

**is it possible to keep newlines in GET request?**

*P.S: I have to make full ajax website, so I can't use forms with regular "POST" method, submit buttons and so on.*

Comment: Are you sure those "whitespaces" aren't newlines?

Comment: @Rocket i used preg_replace("/(\s)+/", "<br>", $my_data); but result is one line string. I also used : str_replace("\n", "<br>", $my_data); but again the result is one line string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nl2br to convert your newlines to HTML breaks

Comment: The problem was the following part of code : $data = preg_replace("/(\s)+/", " ", $data); used before matching new lines, so  I think it also replaced \n with " ", but thanks for the sugestion